# CMake ExternalProject, INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES not propagated

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to reference some static libraries from a CMake project (mod_a) from another one (master) not in the same directory tree, by following [this recipe](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-October/056113.html). The projects generate Visual Studio 2013 targets. master's relevant CMakeLists.txt part is:

```
set(MOD_A_INC "v:/src/git/opencv/install/include")
message(${MOD_A_INC}) # non-empty

ExternalProject_Add(mod_a-external
SOURCE_DIR ${MODULE_ROOT}/a 
BINARY_DIR mod_a-build
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

add_library(mod_a STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mod_a PROPERTIES
IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mod_a-build/mod_a.lib
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MOD_A_INC}" # skipping quotation marks doesn't change things
)
```

A VS solution for mod_a will be created and called correctly in masters's build tree. This solution has an include path, set in mod_a's own CMakeLists.txt file by INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES statements, but the parts from INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES are not propagated and mod_a doesn't compile for this reason.

What am I missing here and could someone shed light on order/priority/interplay of INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES? Are these things merged/appended/overwritten, if both kinds of statements appear?

Comment: `the parts from INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES are not propagated and mod_a doesn't compile for this reason.` - `mod_a` library doesn't compile, because it is **IMPORTED**. Its properties affect only on the target(executable or other library) which is linked with it using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: OK, so INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is intended for the consuming project and anything I intend to change for mod_a, has to go into the ExternalProject_Add call.
How can I inject there additional include directories? There is an option for passing variables, but not an eqivalent for include_directories. What can I do, without changing mod_a's CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: External project should be *self-contained*. If it depends from 3d-party library, it should either search this library automatically(via `find_package()`) or allow to specify it by user via cmake variables. It should be described somewhere in `README` or in `CMakeLists.txt` file for external project.

Comment: I'm afraid, this 3rd-party library is not quite that self-contained. But thank you for pointing me to the meaning of set_target_properties arguments for imported libraries. I'll see, how I can work around this.